# Solving a problem in a more Typescript way

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I'm trying to improve the way I'm solving this particular problem

Situation.

For each Request, I might get a Response | EventNotification.

when dealing this union of either a Response | EventNotification, I can't seem to solve without using typecasting and then branching on if statement

Example:

request:

```
  { 
    type: 'something', age: 22 
  }
```

response can be either:

```
 type TypeOne = {  
  Response: { key: 'key', age: 22}
 }
```

or

```
TypeTwo = { 
 EventNotification: { key: 'trying to process your request' , age: 33 
 }
}
```

Then I have a function that is taking this response and tries a branching, but in order to make the branch work I have to typecast.

```
const a = response as TypeOne
const b  = response as typeTwo


if(a){
// do stuff here safely.
}else {
// do stuff here safely.
}
```

I'll still have to check for existence of both, but I want to not have to typecast.
I hope I'm making myself clear.
Another point could be:
How to make so where in a type, when one property is checked to be truty, in for example a if statement, the other property can't be then accessed? Is that possible?.

Let say:

```
Type A = {
  KeyOne?: { name: string, age: number},
  KeyTwo?: { name: string, height: number}
}

const fn = (a:A) => {
if(a.KeyOne) {
   // access OK
   // a.KeyTwo doesn't exist
 } else if(a.KeyTwo) {
   // access OK;
   // a.KeyOne doesn't exist type Error;
  }
}
```

Can that scenario be modeled with Typescript?
Thanks.

Comment: You could again have if else ,but you will check if the X is instance/type of Response or Notification ,then it will know that the object is 100% the given type

Comment: What are the actual differences between the `Response` and `EventNotification` types? It kind of looks like they're both `{ key: string: age: number }`

Comment: Response and EventNotification are the properties that come from the two types of responses. I edited to try and mitigate that. My solution so far was to put both Response property and EventNotification property in a higher Type then make both optional, that way I don't need to typecast, the only problem is that I can't actually eliminate the existence of one,  based on the existence of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you want a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) which acts as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) where you can check one property to filter the union.  Here's how I would do it:

```
type A =
  { KeyOne: { name: string, age: number }, KeyTwo?: never } |
  { KeyOne?: never, KeyTwo: { name: string, height: number } }
```

The type `A` is one of two possible types: an object with a defined `KeyOne` property and an `undefined` `KeyTwo` property (an optional property of type `never` will always be `undefined` when you read from it), or an object with a defined `KeyTwo` property and an `undefined` `KeyOne` property.  Since TypeScript 3.2, [this acts as a discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants).  You can see it work as you expect:

```
const fn = (a: A) => {
  if (a.KeyOne) {
    a.KeyOne.age; // okay
    a.KeyOne.name; // okay
    a.KeyTwo.name; // error! Object is undefined
  } else {
    a.KeyTwo.name; // okay
    a.KeyTwo.height; // okay
    a.KeyOne.name; // error! Object is undefined
  }
}
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8AoKUDeUDSEQHkB2EAXGlHgIYC2RUAzsAE4CWeA5gDRRkvV4CuFAIwj0oAXw5YQAFQDuAewD8xAgDdhYqAB9kJSfghLSENfQnZZc4unJVidJqw4ALCIxZPgy-kJGixiRABjOTw6KAAzPAQoAAoyYhgASgQAPjQdRnDYsgA6PQJk1B0UXPyIHK4IAG4oAHpaqDkAazIQYs487H0cm2q6hubW9tLzeR7KPvqoYXo5egBCKBwBACsIQOAoRhooXjwAEwhw5gh9nT8IABsaaCKUEs7pMd6aqcG2+47JCxyXNw9XgMWh97iNcARxlRAdN6LMFktVutNttdgcjiczihRIhREA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, reading the type A signature made me realize what I could have thought, clever.